# Using smart pointer for critical section

Tags: c++, mutex, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, critical-section

What is the drawbacks or errors in the following approach to use non-owning `std::unique_ptr` having custom deleter to arrange a critical section?

```
#include <memory>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <optional>
#include <variant>

#include <cassert>

struct Data
{
    std::optional<int> i;
};

struct DataLocker
{
    std::variant<std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>, std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>> lock;

    void operator () (const Data *)
    {
        std::visit([] (auto & lock) { if (lock) lock.unlock(); }, lock);
    }
};

struct DataHolder
{
    std::unique_ptr<Data, DataLocker> getLockedData()
    {
        return {&data, {std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>{m}}};
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<const Data, DataLocker> getLockedData() const
    {
        return {&data, {std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>{m}}};
    }

private :
    mutable std::shared_mutex m;
    Data data;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    DataHolder d;
    auto producer = [&d]
    {
        d.getLockedData()->i = 123;
    };
    auto consumer = [&d = std::as_const(d)]
    {
        for (;;) {
            if (const auto i = d.getLockedData()->i) {
                std::cout << *i << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    std::thread p(producer);
    std::thread c(consumer);
    p.join();
    c.join();
}
```

One corner case, when writer `reset()`s a pointer and never destruct `std::unique_ptr` itself is covered by adding `unlock` to deleter's `operator ()`.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated. Why not just use a `unique_lock` all the time? The `shared_mutex m` is mutable so you can use it from a const method.

Comment: @RaymondChen Complicated in which respect? Read-only access can be shared among multiple threads. `shared_mutex m` already used from `const` method.

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to use a `shared_lock` for read-only access and a `unique_lock` for read-write access. I think it would be less confusing to give the two `getLockedData()` methods different names (`lockExclusive()` and `lockShared()`). For one thing, it makes it possible to get a shared lock from a non-const DataHolder. I also think it's confusing that the same DataLocker is used for the two different kinds of locks. It means that the holder of the DataLocker doesn't know what kind of access they have.

Comment: @RaymondChen you right